# How to send Textbox value to ActionLink in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Here is my scenario

```
@Html.Textbox("value")
```

how to pass above text box value to below action link

```
@Html.ActionLink("Search","Search",new {firstname=value)
```

Comment: Where do you want to do this? Client side? After posting to the server? Have you tried anything that hasn't worked?

Comment: in controller ,server side

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it using javascript.
First generate the anchor tag with a href having a faked value of firstname:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Search", "Controller", new {firstname="xxxx"}") id="lnk">Search</a>
```

Also, generate the  with an ID (i.e. txtSearch).

Then, using javascript you can attach the click event of this . Using jQuery code will be something like:

```
$("#lnk").click(function(evt) {
    var fakedUri = $("#lnk").prop("href");
    var uri = fakedUri.replace("xxxx", $("#txtSearch").val());
});
```

Greetings!

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to use your code, but I'm getting the XXXX in my controller, not the value of the textbox. is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Ok I got the solution. I just needed to add uri as lnk's href prop again.  $("#lnk").prop("href", uri); has done the trick.

Comment: @Jain you just saved me from hours of wondering why it didn't work. Also, .prop() was not available in my version of jquery, I had to use .attr() for anyone else with this issue. Thanks

Comment: @eiximenis i have 5 parameters then how to pass it ??

Comment: Just use same pattern:
<a href="@Url.Action("action","controller", new {p1="xxx", p2="yyy"}" id=lnk">...</a>

var uri = fakedUri.replace("xxx", valueOfParam1).replace("yyy", valueOfParam2)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a form

```
<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("Search", "Search")">
     @Html.Textbox("value")
</form>
```

Comment: is it possible to with out using form, because we are planned to implement search functionality on index page...

Comment: yes, you can use Javascript to perform a POST to the url. jQuery AJAX is useful for this - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/